# Suite CRM - The zip file is missing a manifest.php file. Cannot proceed

Tags: php, module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created a custom module in Suite CRM but when try to upload it via Module Loader it gives this error

> The zip file is missing a manifest.php file.

Cannot proceed even though the manifest.php file is there in the root directory of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permission related issue

- Try setting your whole sugar instance to 755 recursively(-R 755)
- Then within your sugar instance set the folders cache, custom, data, modules, & themes to 775 recursively(-R 775)
- quick repair and rebuild and try installing again

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check those things:

- cases of letters in a filename of your manifest.php (on case-sensitive filesystems 'Manifest.php' or 'manifest.PHP' is not the same filename as 'manifest.php')
- manifest.php is in the root of the **zip file** and not in *any* subfolder

Comment: the file is in the root of the zip folder and is named as manifest.php.

Comment: There shouldn't be a "zip folder". the manifest has to be directly in there. After unzipping what is the path of the manifest.php?

Answer (score 0):

**One of the issue that can cause this to happen is putting *manifest.php* in the module folder.**
Do Not put the *manifest.php* inside folder to which you want to create the module.
Create the *manifest.php* file outside the module folder and then create a .zip file by selecting both of them.