# SuiteCRM - The zip file is missing a manifest.php file. Cannot proceed

Tags: php, suitecrm

I have exported the `Meetings` module from `SuiteCRM`, renamed all the occurrences to `Events` module, zipped it. Now when I try to upload the file to `SuiteCRM` it says

> The zip file is missing a manifest.php file. Cannot proceed.

I have tried with multiple archivers(default, terminal and some other), getting the same error every time.

I have also tried with the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271884/suite-crm-the-zip-file-is-missing-a-manifest-php-file-cannot-proceed), but nothing working.

Here is directory structure. *manifest.php* is present in the zip and folder as well.

```
./.DS_Store
./Extension/modules/Events/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_jjwg_maps_address_c.php
./Extension/modules/Events/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_jjwg_maps_lng_c.php
./Extension/modules/Events/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_jjwg_maps_lat_c.php
./Extension/modules/Events/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_jjwg_maps_geocode_status_c.php
./manifest.php
./SugarModules/.DS_Store
./SugarModules/include/.DS_Store
./SugarModules/include/language/en_us.Events.php
./SugarModules/modules/.DS_Store
./SugarModules/modules/Events/logic_hooks.php
./LICENSE.txt
```

```
Version 7.8.27
Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)
```

am I missing something while exporting, importing or zipping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone having the same issue, I guess this will help a bit.

I tried all the things that are mentioned anywhere and everywhere. Still was unable to get module imported. The steps are below that you need to follow.

- Export module.
- Unzip the folder and change all occurrences from `ActualModule`(`Meetings` in my case) to `CustomModule`(`Events` in my case.)
- Check if there is any key left in `Vardefs`. This could be normally singular(like `Meeting`) and change it to singular(`Event`).
- Save all the changes.
- **Zip all the contents of the directory. Yes, the contents only, not the directory itself**. In my case it was *Events-XXXXXX* and I was zipping the directory itself. Just zip the contents that are inside the *Events-XXXXXX* directory.
- Import module within the CRM with `Module Loader` and install it.